# ¿Cómo se puede obtener los días de un mes en js?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo se puede obtener los días de un mes en js?

(Quiero los datos que estan en negrita)

El dia numero **1** del mes x del año x es **Martes**

El dia numero **2** del mes x del año x es **Miercoles**

...

Supongo que es con date

```
var dias = new Date(2019, 2);
```

con `dias.getDay()` obtengo el día de la semana y con `dias.getDate()` obtengo el día del mes pero necesito estos datos de todos los días de un mes.

Comment: a que te refieres con los días de un mes? cuales días? bajo que criterio? mejora tu pregunta

Comment: @element editado

Comment: quieres los nombres de los días? o necesitas el nombre y el número de un mes en particular?

Comment: @Paulo Urbano Rivera  quiero el numero y el dia de todos dias de un mes en particular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para saber cuantos días tiene un mes y así poder iterarlo puedes usar un pequeño truco:

```
new Date(año, mes, 0).getDate()
```

Cuando le indicas 0 en el parámetro de días al constructor, lo interpreta como "el día anterior al 1" es decir el último día del mes pasado. Por otro lado el constructor de `Date` usa los números del 0 al 11 para los meses, entonces si quiero el número de días de febrero le paso 2.

```js
var año = 2019;
var mes = 2;

var diasMes = new Date(año, mes, 0).getDate();
var diasSemana = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];

for (var dia = 1; dia <= diasMes; dia++) {
  // Ojo, hay que restarle 1 para obtener el mes correcto
  var indice = new Date(año, mes - 1, dia).getDay();
  console.log(`El día número ${dia} del mes ${mes} del año ${año} es ${diasSemana[indice]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que esta informacion te podria servir para solucionar este problema de las fechas con Js, solo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>

Date.getDaysInMonth(2019, 1)
```

Y para que te sirva este Js puede descargarlo desde este gitlab

https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

Si tienes alguna duda no olvides comentar. Saludos!.

Comment: Pero esa función sólo te retorna la cantidad de días que tiene un mes en particular =/ , no es lo que necesita el OP